# Call dot net library function from python in QGis

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, .net

I have created one custom library (.dll) in Dot net. Now, i want to use that dll in my QGis plugin. How i can integrate that?

For an example i have one function in library which is used to read excel file and dump all the data in database. so from QGis plugin i will browse the excel file and using the library i will read excel data and dump data in my database. all the database related operation will be perform by library.

Comment: This seems to be two questions, one about Iron Python and the previous one that seems broader than Iron Python.  Please [edit] to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Does the .NET library do anything that you can't redo in Python?

Comment: I have used Entity framework for interact with SQL server database. I think which is  not possible using python.

Comment: 100% possible. Many different ways, one of which is `QSqlDatabase` and `QSqlQuery`

Comment: True, it is possible but if in case i want to use my dot net library can i use it?